# Android, Null Pointer Exception on ListView test code

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, nullpointerexception, listadapter

I am building an app that uses ListView and a custom adapter extending BaseAdapter to handle the data to the ListView. The code is as follows:

**newlist.java** compiles/runs fine

```
public class newslist extends Activity {

    public static final String tag = "newslist";
    ListView listNews;
    MyListAdapter listAdapter;


    /** Set or Grab the URL */        
    public static final String parseURL = "http://www.example.com.gr/article.php";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.newslist);

        /** Array Lists */
        ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> links = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> dates = new ArrayList<String>();

        Log.d(newslist.tag, "****** parseURL = " + parseURL);

        listNews = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listNews);

        try {                  
            /** Open URL with Jsoup */
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(parseURL).get();

            /** Grab classes we want */                   
            Elements pcontent = doc.getElementsByClass("content_title");
            Elements pdates = doc.getElementsByClass("content_datecreated_left");

            /** Loop for grabbing TITLES within parent element */
            for (Element ptitles : pcontent) {

                /** Grab Anchors */
                Elements ptitle = ptitles.getElementsByTag("a");
                for (Element title : ptitle) {
                  titles.add(title.text());
                }
            }

            /** Loop for grabbing LINKS within parent element */
            for (Element plinks : pcontent) {
                /** Grab anchors */
                Elements plink = plinks.getElementsByTag("a");
                for (Element link : plink) {                    
                  links.add(link.attr("abs:href")); /** parse absolute address */    
                }
            }

            /** Loop for grabbing DATES within parent element */
            for (Element pdate : pdates) {
                dates.add(pdate.text()) ;
            }

            //TODO: Regex on Date

            //String content: Main Activity Content

            int i=0;
            int num = titles.size();
            String[] printDates = new String[num];
            for (i=0; i < num; i++)
            {
                //substring(25) leaves a space after the date, eg "26/6/2011 "
                //content[i] = titles.get(i) + "\n Date: " + dates.get(i).substring(25);
                printDates[i] = dates.get(i).substring(25);
            }

            /** Create an ArrayAdapter, that will actually make the Strings above 
             * appear in the ListView */ 
            listAdapter = new MyListAdapter(this, titles, dates);
            listNews.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(newslist.tag, "****** Failed to Parse URL:" + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

    } /*- OnCreate End -*/

} /*- Class End -*/
```

**MyListAdapter.java** runs a NPE at line 75:

```
public class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public final static String tag = "MyListAdapter";
    public Context context;
    public ArrayList<String> title;
    public ArrayList<String> date;
    public LayoutInflater inflater;

    public MyListAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<String> title, ArrayList<String> date) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.title = title;
        this.date = date;

        this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        // Auto-generated method stub
        return this.title.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        //Auto-generated method stub
        return this.title.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView titleView;
        TextView dateView;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        // Auto-generated method stub
        ViewHolder holder;

        Log.d(tag, "****** convertView: " + convertView);

        if (convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listrow, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.titleView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listTitle);
            holder.dateView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listDate);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        Log.d(tag, "****** Title: " + title.get(position));
        Log.d(tag, "****** findViewById: " + convertView.findViewById(R.id.listTitle));
        Log.d(tag, "****** holder.titleView: " + holder.titleView);


        holder.titleView.setText(title.get(position));
        holder.dateView.setText(date.get(position));

        //notifyDataSetChanged();

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Line 75 is:

```
holder.titleView.setText(title.get(position));
```

However I have tracked the problem to line 62:

```
holder.titleView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listTitle);
```

where it seems from my debugging messages that **holder.titleView** is *null*

I have tried cleaning/erasing bin folder and rebuilding the project to no avail. I think the problem lies in the View R.id.listTitle not being found. But i have no idea why.

I will also include my two xml files for previewing

**newslist.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:gravity="center|top"
    android:textSize="20dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="@string/titleNewslist"
    />
<ListView  
    android:id="@+id/listNews"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**listrow.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:name="@+id/listTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:textSize="18dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="TextView">
    </TextView>  
    <TextView
        android:name="@+id/listDate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom|right"
        android:textSize="12dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:text="TextView">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: just try to change the name of the Textview in the xml and give some   other name and check what happens.

Comment: Thank guys the problem is solved! I had made a typo in the XML android:name instead of android:id. Silly me :| Do I flag this question as answered somehow? It's my first post in stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never assign anything to titleView.

You need to do the following in your onCreate() after super.onCreate()

```
titleView = (TextView) this.getViewById(R.id.listTitle);
```

Make sure to declare titleView as a field at the top of your class so the rest of your class can access it, if you need to.

Hope this helps!

EDIT:

An important note I just noticed:

```
android:name="@+id/myName"
```

is NOT the same as

```
android:id="@+id/myName"
```

You need to make sure you declare the ids, or you will not be able to access the layout elements.

Comment: Thanx for the fast reply! I already have the following line in my Adapter class:
holder.titleView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listTitle);

Were you reffering to my main class, newslist.java?

Comment: Yes, you need to call that bit of code wherever you want to access a layout element.  You should (generally) never use static references to view elements, because they do not exist until onCreate() is called, and you get NullReferenceExceptions like you're having now :)

Comment: OMG I just noticed the android:name instead of "id" - been tired after so many hours. Thanks for that! It was of course the seed of my problem!! Everything works fine now ;)

Comment: Glad to know I helped! :)  As a new user, make sure you upvote and mark correct answers when your question is answered :)

Comment: Yeah I upvoted you but it said I needed 15 points or sth. Marked the answer as helpful though. Do i need to mark the post as Solved or something?

Comment: Yes, mark my answer as correct if it solved your problem.  This will let other users see that the problem is solved so they won't reply to this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the use of ViewHolder.

You should do :

```
convertView = new YourViewClass();
```

in this class have 2 fields for both textviews and a onCreate that inflate listRow.xml and find both views by id.

but converview and view holder should not be different and you should not try to pass one view from one component to the other.

Regards,
 Stéphane

Answer (score 0):

NullPointerException usually comes, when you have some problems with your XML files. Try to not end your

```
<TextView
    android:name="@+id/listTitle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="top|left"
    android:textSize="18dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="TextView">
</TextView>
```

with > and  instead of > and

I'm not sure that it's the source of your problem, but it can happen.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

you are passing the Activity context into the MyListAdapter constructor and assign to the Context object.

change the Activity to Context in constructor and then try it